# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BPP.BPPCCSPCollabCacService.CAC>' to 'BPPCCSPCollabCacService.CAC[]'

Tags: c#

I am trying to import from excel to to my application and also save it using asp.net mvc but I got this error

[Cannot Convert from 'List' to 'T[]'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJCqn.png)

**ICacService**

```
public interface ICacService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ApplyDataContractResolver]
    CheckResult CheckCacImportData(string fileName, List<CAC> importCacData);

    [OperationContract]
    [ApplyDataContractResolver]
    void SaveCacImportData(IEnumerable<CAC> importCacData);
}
```

**CacService**

```
    public class CacService : ICacService
{

    public CheckResult CheckCacImportData(string fileName, List<CAC> importCacData)
    {
        var result = new CheckResult();

        var targetFile = new FileInfo(fileName);

        if (!targetFile.Exists)
        {
            result.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            result.Success = false;
            result.ErrorCount = 0;
            result.ErrorMessage = "Data Import Error!";
            return result;
        }

        var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);

        //
        //excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ID, "ID");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.RC_NUMBER, "RC Number");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.COMPANY_NAME, "Company Name");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE, "Ownership Structure");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ADDRESS_STREET, "Street");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ADDRESS_CITY, "City");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ADDRESS_STATE, "State");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ADDRESS_PMB, "PMB");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ADDRESS_POBOX, "PO Box");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.ADDRESS_LGA, "LGA");
        excelFile.AddMapping<CAC>(x => x.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, "Registration Date");

        //SheetName
        var excelContent = excelFile.Worksheet<CAC>("List of CAC");

        int errorCount = 0;
        int rowIndex = 1;
        var importErrorMessages = new List<string>();

        //
        foreach (var row in excelContent)
        {
            var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
            var cacRecord = new CAC();

           // cacRecord.ID = row.ID;
            cacRecord.ADDRESS_STREET = row.ADDRESS_STREET;
            cacRecord.ADDRESS_CITY = row.ADDRESS_CITY;
            cacRecord.ADDRESS_STATE = row.ADDRESS_STATE;
            cacRecord.ADDRESS_PMB = row.ADDRESS_PMB;
            cacRecord.ADDRESS_POBOX = row.ADDRESS_POBOX;
            cacRecord.ADDRESS_LGA = row.ADDRESS_LGA;
            cacRecord.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION = row.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION;
            cacRecord.ACTION_STATUS = 1;
            cacRecord.CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now;

            //RC Number
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.RC_NUMBER))
            {
                errorMessage.Append("RC - Cannot be Blank. ");
            }
            cacRecord.RC_NUMBER = row.RC_NUMBER;

            //Company Name
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.COMPANY_NAME))
            {
                errorMessage.Append("Company Name - Cannot be Blank. ");
            }
            cacRecord.COMPANY_NAME = row.COMPANY_NAME;

            //Ownership Structure
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE))
            {
                errorMessage.Append("Ownership Structure - Cannot be Blank. ");
            }
            cacRecord.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE = row.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE;

            //=============================================================================
            if (errorMessage.Length > 0)
            {
                errorCount += 1;
                importErrorMessages.Add(string.Format(
                    "Error {0} Windows cannot access this device：{1}{2}",
                    rowIndex,
                    errorMessage,
                    "<br/>"));
            }
            importCacData.Add(cacRecord);
            rowIndex += 1;
        }

        try
        {
            result.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            result.Success = errorCount.Equals(0);
            result.RowCount = importCacData.Count;
            result.ErrorCount = errorCount;

            string allErrorMessage = string.Empty;

            foreach (var message in importErrorMessages)
            {
                allErrorMessage += message;
            }

            result.ErrorMessage = allErrorMessage;

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// Saves the import data.
    public void SaveCacImportData(IEnumerable<CAC> importCacData)
    {
        try
        {
            //Add or Remove
            using (var db = new COLLABEntities())
            {
                foreach (var item in db.CAC.OrderBy(x => x.CAC_ID))
                {
                    db.CAC.Remove(item);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            //Save and Comit file
            using (var db = new COLLABEntities())
            {
                foreach (var item in importCacData)
                {
                    db.CAC.Add(item);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(string savedFileName)
    {
        var jo = new JObject();
        string result;

        try
        {
            var fileName = string.Concat(Server.MapPath(fileSavedPath), "/", savedFileName);
            var importCacData = new List<CAC>();
            //var helper = new ImportDataHelper();
            var helper = new CacServiceClient();
            var checkResult = helper.CheckCacImportData(fileName, importCacData);

            jo.Add("Result", checkResult.Success);
            jo.Add("Msg", checkResult.Success ? string.Empty : checkResult.ErrorMessage);

            if (checkResult.Success)
            {
                helper.SaveCacImportData(importCacData);
            }
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return Content(result, "application/json");
    }
```

Please kindly help. Where have I got it wrong I tried to call the service from my controller using **var helper = new CacServiceClient();** But I got the errors in the diagram.

Comment: We only need the relevant code.  This would be where the error occurred and possibly your class.

Comment: From : public CheckResult To : public List<CheckResult>

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and sample, I'm assuming you're using WCF and you created a proxy, called a method on it and got this error.

The problem is that WCF serializes collections as arrays over the wire. If you want to use the `List<T>` class, you have to configure the proxy generator to generate lists instead of arrays.

Among the configuration options of the service reference, there's an 'Advanced' option, and under that you can choose to deserialize collections into `List<T>` instead of an array.

Comment: Please how do I do that

Comment: Check out [this](http://mshelp.be/how-to-configure-a-wcf-proxy-to-return-a-generic-list-259.htm) post for screenshots and a detailed step-by-step:

Comment: Thanks a lot problem solved. But other issues came up. `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BOARD_OF_DIRECTORS>' to 'System.IO.Stream'`

Comment: I suggest you close this question and open a new one with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and pinpoint the exact location of this new exception with more detailed information.

Comment: Any solution please